# How to decode a string in base64 with php

Tags: php, encryption, des

Hello i'm trying to decrypt a base64 string with php and i can't figure it out.

I am able to decrypt it with JavaScript using CryptoJS with the code below

```
var data = 'encrypted_url';
var key = "my_token";

function decryptByDES(cipherTextString, keyString) {
  var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyString);

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherTextString)
  }, keyHex, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  });
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

console.log(decryptByDES(data, key);
```

What is the equivalent of this code in PHP?

Comment: `base64_decode()`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode and decode from base64 a string can use base64_encode() :

```
<?php
$str = 'This is an encoded string';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

and now to decode:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

Now can apply this with any function.

Now this function could do the same using php 7.1:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
$key = '12345678';


function decryptByDES($str, $key) {
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    $key = base64_decode($key);
    $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $str = str_replace("\x0", '', $str);
    return $str;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.

The solution to my problem was the code below

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode("encrypted_url"), 'DES-ECB', utf8_decode("my_token"), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING , '');
```